# Jetty-Maven-Plugin reads jettyXml and still starts default context

Tags: embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am using Jetty 8.1.4.v20120524 and Maven 3. I have the following configuration in my pom:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
    <configuration>
      <jettyXml>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

In my jetty.xml, I define a context:

```
<Set name="handler">
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList">
    <Set name="handlers">
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
            <Set name="welcomeFiles">
              <Array type="String"><Item>index.xml,index.xhtml,index.html</Item></Array>
            </Set>
          </New>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
            <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="src/main/webapp" /></Set>
            <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
          </New>
        </Item>
      </Array>
    </Set>
  </New>
</Set>
```

This works as expected and starts my application at /:

```
INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.4.v20120524
INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/<MY_DIRECTORY>/src/main/webapp/}
INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/<MY_DIRECTORY>/src/main/webapp/}
```

However, after this the jetty-maven-plugin seems to try to start a default context, which fails with class not found - It also tries to bind to "/", which I obviously don't want.

```
WARN:oejs.Holder:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.basex.http.rest.RESTServlet
INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/<MY_DIRECTORY>/src/main/webapp/},file:/<MY_DIRECTORY>/src/main/webapp/
INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/<MY_DIRECTORY>/src/main/webapp/},file:/<MY_DIRECTORY>/src/main/webapp/
INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/<MY_DIRECTORY>/src/main/webapp/},file:/<MY_DIRECTORY>/src/main/webapp/
```

How can I stop this context to be started? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an Answer on the mailing list (http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg02419.html) by Jan Bartel the web app currently can not be configured solely with the jetty.xml.

I therefore resolved the issue by moving the web app related stuff (resource base and context path) to the maven pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I was using version 8.1.4.v2012052 of jetty-maven-plugin and attempting to set the contextPath in pom.xml with something like:

```
<configuration>
<webAppConfig>
    <contextPath>${application.contextpath}</contextPath>
</webAppConfig> 
...
</configuration>
```

Yet, the contextPath still defaulted to "/".

I downgraded to version 7.5.1.v20110908 with the same configuration in pom.xml. The intended contextPath did then show.

Thus, I think this may be an issue with the 8.1.4 version that is resolved by downgrading.